# What is the activation function of a feedforward neural network that corresponds to GLM?

Tags: neural-networks, generalized-linear-model

I am reading a slide which says GLM are neural networks.
https://owars.info/mario/2020_Wuthrich.pdf

The authors showed that if you have an exponential function as the activation function of a very simple 1-layer neural network, then it corresponds to Poisson regression, which is a type of GLM.

My question is: for the general GLM, what should be the corresponding activation function if the GLM were represented as a neural network?

Comment: the key is to have only one layer; different activations would correspond to different "link functions" in GLM parlance; there is no single activation function which makes a neural net into a GLM.

Comment: It is worth noting that a $\log$ link is not synonymous with Poisson regression. A $\log$ link could be used for other likelihoods, such as gamma or negative binomial (even Gaussian is theoretically possible). Thus, the claim that an exponential activation function (inverse of a logarithmic link function) corresponds to Poisson regression is not correct. // I once posted a possible related [question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/21080/25529) on AI.SE.

Comment: It is the combination of corresponding loss, inverse link activation and 0 hidden layer architecture that mimics a GLM via gradient descent. Exactly how it is written in Mario's notes, btw.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My question is: for the general GLM, what should be the corresponding activation function if the GLM were represented as a neural network?

If you have a model for the expectation of the form:

$$\mu = g^{-1}(X\beta)$$

In GLM jargon, $X\beta=\eta$ is the linear prediction, and $g$ is the link function.

Then it can be equally stated as a neural network with a single layer and $g^{-1}$ as the activation function.

Note, however, as @Sycorax and @Dave mentioned, a linear predictor and a link function do not a GLM make.
A GLM also has another component: an assumption on the conditional expectation of the response variable.
In GLMs, we assume the response is distributed, conditional on the predictors, according to a particular distribution from the exponential family.
Different choices entail different likelihoods.

Comment: But just to be 100% clear, there's no single $g^{-1}$ that is held in common across all of the different GLM families. And each probability family has its own likelihood, so the functions under optimization likewise vary.

Comment: @Sycorax true, I should add that

Comment: The answer misses an important aspect: the choice of corresponding loss function.

Comment: @MichaelM that's the likelihood part

Comment: @Firebug: for the GLM yes, but for the nn it is simply a loss.

Answer (score 5):

An activation function alone does not make a neural network into a GLM. There are three defining features of a GLM:

1. The loss function. A GLM maximizes the likelihood of a probability model, so to make a NN into a GLM, we need to optimize the same function.
2. No hidden layers. A G***L***M is a *linear* model, so our NN must also be a linear model.
3. The link function. GLMs use a link function to relate the linear predictor to the likelihood, and we need the NN to match that.

Here's an example of how to put these facts together to make a logistic regression NN. [Is logistic regression a specific case of a neural network?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/500948/is-logistic-regression-a-specific-case-of-a-neural-network/500973#500973)

And a general recipe for getting losses that correspond to exponential family losses, such as those used in GLMs [How to construct a cross-entropy loss for general regression targets?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/378274/how-to-construct-a-cross-entropy-loss-for-general-regression-targets)

But no particular regression model is a "general GLM," so there is no neural network that corresponds to a "general GLM."